# Unable to change style of ng-multiselect dropdown

Tags: css, angular

Am using Angular 6 App. I want to change the style of ng-multiselect-dropdown. If i override the style using inline,external and internal, it does not affect anything. Only if i change the style in node modules the change effects in UI. But it is not the correct way.How should i achieve this?

style.css

```
.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn .dropdown-down {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #adadad;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to create a Stackblitz that demonstrates the issue please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70101266/7186739

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use **!important** to you custom ccs inside style.css file
   like:
   display: inline-block !important;
2. **second solution** you can make component **ViewEncapsulation.None**

I thing this may work..