# set width of ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: css, angular6

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown. I want to set its width to 100pt.

I already tried using some css

```
.multiselect-dropdown {
    widht:100pt;
}
.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {
    widht:100pt;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I defined custom class and gave width. But point to note is **!important** application. It overrides existing css of ng-multiselect where width is defined as 100%.

CSS

```
.custom-font-size .multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {
    width: 100pt !important; 
}
```

HTML

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown #reporteedropDown class="custom-font-size....">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reference following code:

CSS

```
::ng-deep .multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {
    width: 97%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update the style of ng-multiselect-dropdown**
:first add your own/custom class in multiselect and then use this class as parent selector

**html**

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
   class="customClass"
   [settings]="dropdownSettings"
   [data]="dropdownList"
   (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
   (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
 </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**css**

```
.customClass.dropdown-btn{
    width: 50% !important;
    border:1px solid red !important;
}
```